# How would I implement if a key is held down?

Tags: python, msvcrt

I've searched a lot of threads about this issue but none seem to meet my needs. I'm intending on implementing this code into a script that uses the terminal for use, so using something like pygame is really awkward. I'm doing this for personal use, so any Windows OS dependent solutions would work.

Essentially, I want Python to make the variable keyState equal to LOW if a key is pressed/held and HIGH as long as it's not being pressed. I've tried using mscvrt but it hasn't worked. I would think this would world, but it doesn't :

```
import msvcrt

keyState = 'HIGH'

while True:
  while msvcrt.kbhit():
    isPressed = 'LOW'
    print(isPressed)
    msvcrt.getch()
  isPressed = 'HIGH'
  print(isPressed)
```

I understand this is pretty simple, but I've had a lot of trouble getting something really simple like this to work. Any help is appreciated :)

Another solution that can somehow make keyPressed a boolean variable that's true whenever a key is pressed/held seems like the most elegant solution, but I'm fine with using anything!

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Oops! I forgot to explain, my bad. Whenever you run it, the program will only output HIGH even if you press a key or not. What's strange is if you delete the isPressed = HIGH line, then the rest of the program will work like normal, where as long as you hold down a key it will spam LOW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested)

```
import msvcrt
import time

keystate = 'HIGH'
while True:
  if msvcrt.kbhit():
    keystate = 'LOW'
    msvcrt.getch()
  else:
    keystate = 'HIGH'
  # you may want to put a time.sleep() call here
  # to avoid eating up CPU
  time.sleep(0.1)
  print(keystate)
```

Comment: I added msvcrt.getch() below the keystate = 'LOW' statement so that it flushes the kbhit after pressing a key (if you don't it gets stuck on low). It almost almost works, but if you hold a key it will output something like "L H H H L L L L L L ..." I'm guessing this is because of how key events work on Windows in general where if you hold a key it will put the key, then wait a bit, and then start spamming. Is there any way to overcome this? It nearly works :) thanks!

Comment: You are right.  I edited my code.  (As I've told, I cannot test since msvcrt is not available on my platform).  What you describe is probably caused by keyboard repeat mechanism.  Is the `curses` module available on your system (if so, look at python doc)?

Comment: UniCurses is a Windows version similar to it. I'll try to figure out something with it :) thanks

Comment: I tried the program in a MSWin virtual machine.  It does not work in the Idle environment, but it does work when I run it by double-clicking on the program file (it then runs in a console).  N.B. I also reduced the sleep time to 0.1 second.

Comment: Thanks! I just need it to run from the command prompt so it's fine. (I read somewhere else it's just because msvcrt doesn't work in IDLE in general) Now I just have to get around this whole keyboard thing where holding a key won't delay after the initial output :/ I'm still getting the whole (keyPress) L H H H L L L L ... issue. When making my repeat delay the slowest it can be it still just barley outputs a high temporarily. I suppose I could put a time.sleep(.1) in the msvcrt.kbhit if statement and that may just solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes here for reference, here is my final code that will output HIGH or LOW once the state changes. Make sure your keyboard delay speed on Windows is set to the fastest it can be

```
import msvcrt
import time

keyState = 'HIGH'
while True:
  if msvcrt.kbhit():
    if keyState != 'LOW':
      keyState = 'LOW'
      time.sleep(0.2)
      print(keyState)
    msvcrt.getch()
  else:
    if keyState != 'HIGH':
      keyState = 'HIGH'
      print(keyState)
  time.sleep(0.1)
```